# how to run the php script n times with different set of parameters

Tags: php, loops

I want to run one php script n number of times and I would be passing some variable to that script.
I have tried to loop inside the scripe but thats not working. is there any way so that I can run pho script again and again in loop. I would be passing one variable also and that scrip have to work on that variable. is there any way ?

Comment: What do you mean by "run the script?" This is what functions are for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, and you just want to loop over some PHP code a certain number of times, there is no reason a standard `for` loop would not work:

`for($i = 0; $i < number_of_times; $i++) { ...code... }`

Comment: thanks guys...I actually found out the bug which was creating the problem for me...anways thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code into a function:

```
function myFunction(args...)
{
    //your original script here
}
```

And you can then use a for loop to repeatedly run it with different arguments.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     //collect different arguments
     myFunction(args);
}
```